# How to pass list from controller to view and display

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try get datetime value from user and return selected screening of movie.
Controller passed list to view, but html doesn't change.

Contoller

```
public ActionResult GetScreenings()
            {
                return View();
            }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetScreenings(string starteDateTime, string endDateTime, string movieTitle)
    {
        List<ScreeningDisplayDTO> screeningsList = new List<ScreeningDisplayDTO>();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(movieTitle))
        {
            screeningsList = screeningDisplayService.GetScreeningByParametr(starteDateTime, endDateTime).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            screeningsList = screeningDisplayService.GetScreeningByParametr(starteDateTime, endDateTime, movieTitle).ToList();

        }
        return View(screeningsList);

    }
```

View

```
 @if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var screening in Model)
                    {
                        
                       <p class="offer-film-title">@screening.MovieTitle</p>
                    }
                }
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        traditional: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetScreenings")',
        data: { 'starteDateTime': starteDateTime, 'endDateTime': endDateTime, 'movieTitle': movieTitle  },
        success: function () {
            window.location.href = data;
        }
    });
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ajax  to change your view , you have to use a partial view

```
<div id="partialView">
    
    <partial name="_PartialView" />
        
    </div>
```

and return this partial view from the action and render :

```
  success: function (result) {
             $("#partialView").html(result);
        }
```

Maybe it would be easier for you to use a submit button.

Comment: I have submit button. I had to add **e.preventDefault();**  for my click event  and is now well. Earlier after click submit button controller cause GET action instead of POST. I don't know why.

Comment: I recommend you to use stopImmediatePropagation() too -  $(document).on("click", "#submitBtn", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); }